# Symfony2 how to get the Doctrine EntityManager from a generic object

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an object from inside a Symfony2 project. Here follows the code.
    namespace Acme\UserBundle\Form\Model;

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class Registration
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    protected $user;

    ...

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        //Get the EntityManager here!!!!
        $group = $em
            ->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Group')
            ->findOneByName('Customers');
        $this->user->addGroup($group);
    }
....

}
```

So, as highlighted in the code, how to get the EntityManager to retrieve an entity with Doctrine?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved!

I only have to pass the EntityManager to the constructor of the Registration class within the controller.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User;


class Registration
{
    /**
    * @Assert\Type(type="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
    */
    protected $user;

    ...

    protected $em;    

    public function __construct($em) {
       $this->em = $em;
    }    

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $group = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Group')
            ->findOneByName('Customers');
        $this->user->addGroup($group);
    }
...
}
```

Thanks a lot anyway.